# importing a mysqldump file does not import triggers due to some permission problems

Tags: mysql, permissions

Whenever I try to import a mysqldump export on another server, the triggers are never created, and if I remember correctly, I get an error messages that super user permission is required. IF I remove the definer it usually works but if there is a way I would prefer not having to edit the sql file.

When I just simply copy over the mdi, mdy and frm files everything works perfectly.

How could I import a mysqldump file so that triggers are created as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the user importing the database has the `SUPER` priveledge.